# JQuery .load I need to load content from one url to another

Tags: php, jquery, iframe, canvas, joomla

I want to load content from a div with ID maininner from a URL on my own site http://www.salcombeyurts.com/stage/yurt1.html into a div with id yurt1_avail on another url http://www.salcombeyurts.com/stage/availability.html on the same site.

I have tried a test outside the CMS and it works. I am using this JQuery:

```
<div id="yurt1_avail"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#yurt1_avail').load('yurt1.html #maininner');
});
</script>
```

Is it possible to do this when using CMS/MySQL and .htaccess rewrites for SEF URLs? Is this only possible on static content html pages?.

If this method wont work, what alternatives do I have? I need to load the content of an availability table on one page onto a summary page that will display 3 different availability tables. I am using Joomla and the availability component I have chosen can only be directly linked to, it has no module option or short-code for embedding into articles or modules.

Maybe iFrames could be used, but how would I CSS then to hide all the rest of the page content? I only need the content from #maininner.

Or is there anything in the HTML5/CSS3 markup that will help me?

Answer (score 0):

The AJAX call is an http request so it will work even if you have URL rewriting.

CASE 1 - If you need the content to be uploaded in the main div (the part of the layout where the content is usually shown) then you will have to completely disable your editor (by default is tinyMCE).
Don't try to just edit the HTML source code by clicking the "HTML" button, it won't work because javascript code is cleaned up by TinyMCE.

CASE 2 - If the content of the AJAX request is to be uploaded somewhere else, e.g. in the sidebar, the you'll have to use a Joomla Module, maybe a code-friendly module such as one of these: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-modules